# How old is Hindu religion?

Tags: rituals, worship, history

I want to know how old Hinduism is.

Please provide proper details, references for your answers. Any substantial details with supporting fact or reference is welcome.

Comment: The earliest texts are from some time before the Buddha. This is surmised as commentators often will refer to existing sects at the time and there is no reference to Buddha or Buddhism. The earliest archaeological evidence is from Mohenjo-Daro, Harappa, and Chanhu-Daro. They seemed to reach their climax around 2500 B.C., maybe as old as 4000 B.C. They have found stone lingums, shivas, yogis, mother goddesses from these ruins. It is difficult for any evidence other than stone to survive 6000 years. Source: Myths and Symbols in Indian Art and Civilization by Heinrich Zimmer.